# UWP Print Preview Bug

Tags: c#, .net, printing, windows-10, uwp

I'm using the `Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager` and `Windows.UI.Xaml.Printing.PrintDocument` Classes for showing the preview window and printing a Grid, which has some BitmapImage children.
 I've noticed that everything but those Images are displayed in the preview window, until the preview window itself has been resized or any printing options have been changed (Printer, Papersize, etc...).

After that I created a new blank project and previewed just one image, getting the same results. So I guess it's a Windows "bug" ? 
If anyone knows a workaround/fix I'd gladly appreciate it.

Thanks!